# Right hand and left hand orientation for electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, conventions

An EM wave has an electric and a magnetic field component and in a vacuum both are perpendicular to each other. As you can see from the Wikipedia sketches and my scribbles, the waves in the pictures have opposite relationships of the directions of the field components. This is also understandable because otherwise we would not need right (left) hand rules.

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]

Furthermore, it is known that antenna radiation is polarised radiation and the relation of the E-B-directions is clearly measurable and has led to the right-hand rule.

Are there experiments that have measured, for example, the same hand rule for EM waves from accelerated anti-protons and the opposite hand rule for protons and positrons?

Comment: What rule for accelerated protons/antiprotons, and why are you also mentioning positrons? You might have to be more clear on what right handed rule your asking about here.

Comment: @Triatticus I’ve edited it to say clearer that the rules are about EM waves.

Answer (score 0):

The "right hand rule" arises from the definition of a vector product, which features in the definition of magnetic field and Maxwell's equations. The "handedness" of the E- and B-field directions in an electromagnetic wave arises from the minus sign in Faraday's law. Charge doesn't feature in Faraday's law.

The relationship between the direction of the E-field, B-field and direction of motion of an electromagnetic wave therefore doesn't depend on the source of those waves. The waves illustrated in the question are moving towards positive (top) and negative (bottom) $x$ respectively.

Comment: “The relationship between the direction of the E-field, B-field and direction of motion of an electromagnetic wave therefore doesn't depend on the source of those waves.” That is a fact and that is why I asked for **experiments** with the other charged subatomic particles. Aren't you interested in EM wave phenomena with all kinds of charges and the E-field directions? And there is a way to measure them. Besides electrons, the other charges also emit polarised EM radiation when deflected in magnetic fields in storage rings of particle accelerators. Or in a free-proton laser (if such exist).

Comment: Your reference to Ampere's law is a good moment to point out that - just as with the Lorentz force - a coefficient with a sign that takes the charge into account would actually be possible. Because all these induction laws always refer to electrons. Who was curious so far about how it looks with the other charges?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler the Lorentz force and anything that has the variable q in it doesn't need extra coefficients because q is a real number, it can already take positive, negative, and even zero values. Amperes law already can take charge into account if you define current as the time rate change of charge.

Comment: @Triatticus Exactly. I fully agree with that and that's how my comment was meant. The Lorentz force contains the sign for the charge. Amper's law indirectly does too, but the change of sign for protons and positrons is not accentuated. Indeed, no consideration is even given to how positron currents would behave. And here we are with EM waves of accelerated electrons, whose E and B fields are asymmetrical to each other in space. The second possible arrangement "demands" a solution directly. Proton and positron are candidates for this.